# CASE statement turning a NUMBER into a CHAR, but the ELSE to keep original NUMBER in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm trying to create a simple query that turns a grading/evaluation column that currently contains the values 0,1,2,3,4,5 into Terrible, Poor, Bad, Mediocre, and Good. But as you can see there are only 5 label values but 6 number values.

So the number 5 needs to display as 5, while all the other numbers will turn into their respective labels (Terrible, Poor, etc).

My current query is as follow:

```html
SELECT  course_id,
  student_id,
  CASE eval
  WHEN 0 THEN 'Terrible'
  WHEN 1 THEN 'Bad'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Mediocre'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'Fair'
  WHEN 4 THEN 'Good'
  END
  FROM booking;
```

In the following query result, I know for a fact that the `COURSE_ID` labeled `10121` has an Evaluation value of `5`
All other ones are null so it's fine that they are blank. But `10121` needs to display as `5`.

If I try to apply an `ELSE` statement to return the original value (by doing an `inner select` statement) it says `ERROR at line 9: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER`

```html
 COURSE_ID STUDENT_ID CASEEVAL
---------- ---------- --------
     10111   10235000 Good
     10111   10285858 Fair
     10112   10288497
     10112   10092464 Fair
     10113   10235000
     10114   10128018 Terrible
     10114   10288497
     10115   10092464 Terrible
     10115   10128018 Bad
     10116   10128018
     10118   10288497 Bad
     10118   10836444 Fair
     10119   10285858
     10120   10412445 Mediocre
     10121   10836444
     10122   10285858 Good
     10123   10412445 Mediocre
     10125   10095146
```

Comment: Oracle != MySQL, I fixed your tags.

Comment: That's a case EXPRESSION, not a case statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `ELSE` option to handle the cases that aren't matched. Use `TO_CHAR` to get all the values to the same datatype.

```
SELECT  event_id,
        trainee_id,
        CASE eval
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Terrible'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Bad'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Mediocre'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Fair'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Good'
            ELSE TO_CHAR(eval)
        END
FROM booking;
```

Comment: That still gives me the "inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER" error.

Comment: `TO_CHAR()` should return a `VARCHAR2`, not `NUMBER`. I don't see how it could cause that error.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `'5'`:

```
SELECT  event_id,
        trainee_id,
        (CASE eval
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Terrible'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Bad'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Mediocre'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Fair'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Good'
            WHEN 5 THEN '5'
         END
        )
FROM booking;
```

Alternatively, you can use an explicit `cast()` with a default value using `else`:

```
SELECT  event_id,
        trainee_id,
        (CASE eval
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Terrible'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Bad'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Mediocre'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Fair'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Good'
            ELSE cast(eval as varchar2(255))
         END
        )
FROM booking;
```

I would encourage you to use explicit casts.  SQL can be prone to hard-to-debug errors when doing implicit casts.

Comment: That would work except I need to do it as a possibility of several more instances where a number other than 0-4 is used. So maybe if there was a 6, 7, 8, 9, etc. I don't want to have to write every single number out in the query.

Comment: @Tootally . . . Then use the second query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I believe one uses `ELSE` instead of `DEFAULT` in Oracle SQL `CASE` statements.

Comment: @DavidFaber . . . That is because that is the standard and what every other database does.  I don't know what I was thinking, or at least why my fingers were typing.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use the `DECODE()` function if you don't mind your query's being Oracle-specific:

```
SELECT course_id, student_id
     , DECODE( eval, 0, 'Terrible', 1, 'Bad', 2, 'Mediocre', 3, 'Fair', 4, 'Good', TO_CHAR(eval) )
  FROM booking;
```

Saves a bit of typing in this instance over `CASE` and is also a bit easier to format.

A third option would be to store the evaluation scores and their descriptions in a separate table, then joining (using an outer join) to get the descriptions:

```
SELECT b.course_id, b.student_id, COALESCE(es.eval_desc, TO_CHAR(b.eval))
  FROM booking b, eval_scores es
 WHERE b.eval = es.eval(+)
```